# Showing multiple images in Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, bootstrap-modal

I'm beginning to test bootstrap . So far all goes well, the only problem I have is that when I want to show images in a modal window with carousel , always appears the same image (first image).

The idea of ​​the application is to show the different products with their images , and when the user clicks on a product is a modal window open and show all product photos. The problem is that the modal window always appears the same picture, always shows the first image of the first product, but different products are selected.

A product has many images.

product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, allow_destroy: true
end
```

image.rb

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
end
```

products_controller.rb

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /products
  # GET /products.json
  def index

    @products = Product.by_tipo_and_price(params[:tipo], params[:min], params[:max]).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 9)
  end
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<%- model_class = Product -%>

<div class="page-header">
  <h1>Productos</h1>
</div>

<div class= "row">
  <% @products.each do |product| %>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">

        <!-- Button trigger modal -->
        <% if product.images.empty? %>
          <img data-src="holder.js/160x120" alt="" src="" style="min-height:200px;height:200px;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
        <% else %>
          <img data-src="holder.js/160x120" alt="" src="<%= product.images.first.link %>" style="min-height:200px;height:200px;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
        <% end %>

        <div class="caption" style="min-height:200px;height:200px;">
          <h3><%= product.name %></h3>
          <p>ARS $ <%= product.price %></p>
          <p>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Añadir al carrito</a>
            <a role="button"><%= link_to "Modificar", edit_product_path(product), class: "btn btn-primary" %></a>

            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
              <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-body">

                    <!-- CAROUSEL -->
                    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                      <!-- Indicators -->
                      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                      </ol>

                      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                        <% product.images.each do |i| %>
                          <div class="item active">
                            <img src="<%= i.link %>" alt="...">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                              <%= product.id %>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        <% end %>
                      </div>

                      <!-- Controls -->
                      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                      </a>
                      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>

<%= will_paginate %>

<!-- Modal -->
<%= link_to t('.new', :default => t("helpers.links.new")),
    new_product_path,
    :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

Comment: Try changing `src="<%= product.images.first.link %>"` to `src="<%= product.images.link %>"`

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

```
<img data-src="holder.js/160x120" alt="" src="<%= product.images.first.link %>" style="min-height:200px;height:200px;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#<%= product.id %>">


<div class="modal fade" id="<%= product.id %>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
```